# How to remove ArcGIS 10.0 Server Service and create a new one with the same name?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I want to delete an ArcGIS 10.0 AGS Service and create a new one with the same name. AGS tells me that this is not possible because the Service already exists. I have however deleted the service and the msd and the AGS Cache, but it is still not allowed. What do I need to do so that I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've deleted the service from the "Services" panel in AGS and any relevant folders from the Server Dirtectories which were not deleted, you will need to re-start your instance of server.

I have previously come across this problem and seen other people post about similar problems in the past.  I'm afraid I do not have the links to forum posts I have seen previously about this.  But this method has worked for me.

There are 2 ways to re-start AGS.

You can re-start the machine your server instnace is on.

OR

Assuming you installed server in the default directory, if you browse to this folder

> "C:\app\ESRI\ArcGIS\Server\framework\etc\scripts"

you will see a number of scripts, amongst them there is a "stopserver" and a "startserver" script.

Run the "stopserver" script and wait a few minutes.  Double check that the server is down by trying to access the Server Manager page.

Then run the "startserver" script.  Give it a few minutes.  Check that the serevr is back up and running by trying to access the Server Manager page.

You should now be able to publish your service.